# Accept/Maybe/Decline Missing in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app

I'm using Apple mail with a fresh install of MacOS and I'm missing the Accept/Maybe/Decline buttons on calendar invites. My company uses a Exchange 2013 server and some other users do see the buttons. For me, I just see an email with an attached .ics file for the same invites.

Expected behavior seen by some people....
[image]

How my mail app shows it...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open the Contacts app, select your own email address in the list of contacts. In the menu on top of the screen, go to "Card" -> "Make this my card". Reload calendar. Then it should work, you will get a notification popup with accept/decline buttons. (I just had the same problem, on a Mac running Yosemite)
[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5498622)

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem of the ICS file showing up I think, but when you click the file, it will import the event into the calendar, and then you will have the other problem ;)

Comment: What happens if you are managing multiple accounts on the same calendar? Do you need to keep switching which is "my" card?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After searching forever to find a solution, I stumbled on an unrelated post that fixed the issue. Apparently, if your contact in the Contacts app doesn't have the same email address that you are trying to reply to/from, then you don't get those choices.

Basically, change your contact to be "me" in the Contacts application and they show up. Contacts>Card>Make this my card

Answer (score 1):

on my iPhone:

The email address was already part of "my card". Still, I could not reply to ics-meetings copied to my calendar.

In General settings, Passwords & Accounts: make sure that "calendar" is also selected for the email account in question.

Initially, "calendar" was only selected for my iCloud account, but not all of my additional email accounts.